# OSMF with Basic Authentication

Tags: apache-flex, air, osmf

How would one create a video or audio stream using OSMF when there must be basic authentication on the url?

Can one feed in Audio/Video using HTTPService to provide the header authentication?

All the examples available ignore the authentication portion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

credentials is a string with "username:password" encoded in Base64
For Audio:

```
        private function auth_play(reqestURL:URLRequest) : void {

            stream = new Sound();

            var credsHeader:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);
            reqestURL.requestHeaders.push(credsHeader);

            var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(1000, true);

            stream.load(reqestURL, context);                
        }
```

For Video I couldn't find anything but I SUSPECT this will work with netconnection and netstream:

```
nc.addHeader("Authorization", true, "Basic " + credentials);
```

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here about adding basic authentication to an HTTPService:

[Remote Image with basic authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805957/remote-image-with-basic-authentication/6807604#6807604)

It should do the trick for you :)

Comment: How does one even set the video display source from an HTTPService?